# How to convert PHP array into Mysql resource

Tags: php, mysql, resources, memcached

I have the following scenario. I must run a query and then save it to memory, and if I need the same result again to obtain it from memory.

Storing and reading from memory is made with memcache. The problem is that if you hold information in an array one at a time just have to treat two cases: 1 for resource type and one for array type.

The question is if I can convert an array to Mysql resource type.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't convert an array into a MySQL resource. In fact, why would you want to do that? If you already processed your MySQL results, you can just store them in arrays and use the arrays. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just to add to that, store the array (eg serialized) in memcache, and as key consider using md5(lowercase query string). Then when you look for it you can find it if you have the exact same query string.

Comment: @Fanis: that's more or less what MySQL's query cache does, except it knows when underlying data has changed.

Comment: At this moment I work with both types: arrays and resource. For array I must take keep in a certain way the current element, if I had a Mysql resource it would be much easier. So, I have to stick my head :) to retain and array index. Or I could do this with a specific function?

Comment: @Mchl fair enough. @Emanuel you can't store a mysql resource in memcache. If you have Mysql Query Cache running then just run the same query again, getting a new mysql resource to use when you need it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","foo_dbo","pass") or die("Database error");

mysql_select_db("foo_db", $db);

$sql = "select * from posts;";

$file = sprintf("%s.dat", md5($sql));

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $data[]=$row;

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($db);

if($fp=fopen($file,"w")){
    fwrite($fp,serialize($data));
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

then to read back into an array do something like

```
unserialize(file_get_contents($file))
```

obviously you'd use memcache to store the serialised data not the file system

hope this helps